# how can call function inside class view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have function that return some information about user device and i have one class for show my html and form_class
how can i use function in class

this is my views.py  :

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


def a(request):
    device= request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    print(device)
    return device 


class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("register")
    template_name = "man/man.html"
```

this is my urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.RegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),


]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("register")
    template_name = "man/man.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        def a(request):
            pass
        # remember the import: from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: i do it like this but dont work

Comment: if its work , device must be print in cmd

Comment: but device dont print in cmd with this code

Answer (score 0):

You can build the function into your CBV class, as per Muhammad Shezad's answer.

If the function is long enough and general enough to be used in several views, you can just call it from a subclassed CBV method:

```
from wherever import get_device_info # it needs a much better name than 'a'
class RegisterView( generic.CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid( self, form):
        device_info = get_device_info( self.request)
        ...
```

A third approach, if you always want to use it in the same way in a subclassed method, is to turn it into a Mixin class. For example

```
class GetDeviceMixin( object):
    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup( request, *args, **kwargs)
        # do stuff to get the device information
        self.device_info = whatever
        # all subsequent method invocations will have self.device_info set

class RegisterView( GetDeviceMixin, generic.CreateView):
    ...
```